# Tkinter Entry validatecommand not working as expected

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Python and Tkinter so it is possible (likely) that I'm doing something silly. The following program works (the validation function returns True for valid entries and False for invalid ones) except for one thing: oldvalue == newvalue always. If I type 'xxx' it prints 'wrong!' but the value stays 'xxx'. Validation is supposed to take place before the change takes place and a False return should prevent the change from happening, right?

```
import Tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def makeEntries():
    wnames = []
    def f(name, newvalue, oldvalue):
        name = name[name.rfind('.')+1:]
        print 'validating', name, newvalue, oldvalue
        for i, wn in enumerate(wnames):
            if wn == name:
                if newvalue.isdigit():
                    return True
                else:
                    print 'wrong!'
                    return False
        else:
            raise RuntimeError('Kaput!')
    vcmd = root.register(f)

    frame = tk.Frame(root)
    for i in range(10):
        w = tk.Entry(frame, width=4, justify=tk.RIGHT,
                     validate='focusout',
                     validatecommand=(vcmd, '%W', '%P', '%s'))
        w.pack()
        name = w.winfo_name()
        print i, name
        wnames.append(name)

    return frame

e = makeEntries()
e.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validating on `"focusout"` can't prevent bad values -- the validation mechanism won't delete characters in the widget. It can only prevent characters from being entered at the time the user is typing.